# How to autoamtically run a command when opening db connection in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, database-connection

Specifically, I'm using sqlite, so I need to run the command `PRAGMA foreign_keys=1` on the database every time a connection is opened. How do I tell laravel to do that? Is there a setting somewhere I can specify commands to be run at the start of every connection?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel fires no events between the connection and the first query execution, but you can hook a listeners on queries, it will fire right after the first query is run:

```
DB::listen(function() 
{
    // Run your command here
});
```

But if you need to make sure you want it to ran, maybe the best way should be to fire it on every request, you can do that by executing it in your `app/start/global.php`:

```
DB::statement(DB::raw('PRAGMA foreign_keys=1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 4.2 you have a file named filters.php in your app directory, it has a default filter that fires before every application launch. Meaning it will be run before any controllers or routes.

In case you don't have it in app/filters.php anymore you can add it, it looks like this:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    //
});
```